# CSRF Failure Error Openfire Server Login

Tags: authentication, csrf, openfire

I am getting CSRF Failure issue while login OPenfire Admin Panel. While accessing server with IP Address I am able to login OPenfire admin panel. But while accessing the same server with sub domain at login time I am getting "CSRF Failure" error.

Do I need to enable anything in server configuration or domain configuration?

Any help is appreciated.